# Should I add notes to my question afterwards?

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently asked a question and have accepted an answer, but comments on both the question and answers have shown that my question could've been clearer.

I think that I could edit in notes that would address this and show why I picked the answer that I did, not least because of what I've learnt (especially vocabulary) from the answers.

Would it be appropriate to do this?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to consider this. We often see "drive by" use — folks posting off-the-cuff questions, getting just the info they need, then disappearing, leaving a sometimes confusing trail for a user who comes later to try to learn from. Thinking about your posts for the long term, and how they can offer high-quality Q&A for future users, can really make the site's resources and community stronger. So thank you for taking this to heart, and consulting with other users here to find constructive ways to improve the content together. :)

Comment: Maybe this should be it's own meta question, but other than upvoting, is there any way to incentivize / reward this sort of behavior? Like approving edits with a +2 or +5 rep trade on the grounds of 'Edit improves use w/in context of site."

Answer (score 3):

It is generally suggested that you update the question post and add this kind of details in it instead of adding notes as comments (comments are volatile). If you can integrate the new information in the post instead of adding an "Edit:" section, that would be the best.

You can add more details and narrow the scope.

What's not allowed is changing the scope of the question (such as changing the topic or updating the question with an answer and ask further details (e.g. Q: "I have this issue" A: "You solve it like this" Q: "Ok now I have this new issue based on that answer")).

Comment: +1 As long as you're careful not to change the core question in a way that invalidates existing answers, editing to add clarity and detail is often very helpful.